# download speed when using tor browser

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, speed

sometimes when downloading files through the tor browser i get speed like 2-3MB/sec. that looks suspicious when the usual speed is like 100KB/sec
https://check.torproject.org shows that the browser is configured properly. can i somehow check if everything is all right? would debug logs or something help?

Answer (score 2):

Your connection speed depends on the Tor relays involved in the current circuit. So your best bet is to click on the green onion in the Tor Browser. This will show you all three relays. Use [Atlas](https://atlas.torproject.org/) to check the *Advertised Bandwidth* of those relays. Most probably your circuit will go through high bandwidth relays which results in such high speed and everything is alright.

Answer (score 1):

it's totally OK and it was a fast chain case: tor is **not** limiting the transfer speed in any way.

Comment: Tor limits the transfer speed with its circuit and stream SENDMEs.

Answer (score 1):

TOR is just make it possible that your connection is transferred via 3 extra router:

1. Entry Point
2. Middle Relay
3. Exit Node

The download speed is dependent to 5 factors: **3 extra routers of TOR + the web server (which you're downloading file from) + your ISP speed**. The speed will be the minimum of these factors. As an example, middle relay of your current circuit has limited speed. Therefore, your download speed will be decreased down to your Middle Relay speed limit. **Changing circuit** or **requesting a new identity** may solve your problem.